# Вычесть значение массива из другого значения?

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

Есть такой массив

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [date_sum] => 11.08.2016
                [money] => 100.55
                [money_2] => 40.65
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [date_sum] => 10.08.2016
                [money] => 200.32
                [money_2] => 80.32
            )
...
```

Нужно вычесть money_2 из money и записать рядом, в новый ключ => значение, чтобы получилось так:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date_sum] => 11.08.2016
            [money] => 100.55
            [money_2] => 40.65
            [money_minus] => 59.9
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date_sum] => 10.08.2016
            [money] => 200.32
            [money_2] => 80.32
            [money_minus] => 120
        )
```

Каким способом это правильно сделать?

Comment: видимо через for.... вам же в любом случае придется по всему массиву бежать. так что особо способов выбирать и не приходится........ а вообще если это данные из БД, то 100% можно было это сделать еще в самом запросе

Comment: Что именно в "_вычесть money_2 из money и записать рядом, в новый ключ_" у Вас не получается?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться функцией `array_map()`, написав соответствующую функцию обратного вызова, осуществляющую вычитание элементов массива и вставляющего новый

```
<?php
$arr = [
  [
    'date_sum' => '11.08.2016',
    'money' => '100.55',
    'money_2' => '40.65'
  ],
  [
    'date_sum' => '10.08.2016',
    'money' => '200.32',
    'money_2' => '80.32'
  ]
];
$arr = array_map(
  function($x){
    $x['money_minus'] = $x['money'] - $x['money_2'];
    return $x;
  },
  $arr
);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Обычным циклом [foreach](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php) пройти по массиву

```
$arr = array (
    array (
      'date_sum' => '11.08.2016',
      'money' => '100.55',
      'money_2' => '40.65'
    ),
    array (
      'date_sum' => '10.08.2016',
      'money' => '200.32',
      'money_2' => '80.32'
    )
 );

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $arr[$key]['money_minus'] = $arr[$key]['money'] - $arr[$key]['money_2'];
}

print_r($arr);
```

https://repl.it/CmWe

Answer (score 1):

Можно через [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-walk.php)

```
array_walk($array, function(&$value, $key){
     ...
});
```